# Check UNC Path folder exists

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, smb, network-share

EDIT: I have this code, and now i have to get the output of the command "net view" in a Multiline textbox..

(I don't have to necessary use "net view", i just need something that prints all the shares of a computer in the textbox, like the image posted below)

[Image: Shared resources.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv8Tu.png)

```
Private Sub Ok_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click

        TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Aqua
        TextBox2.Text = "-------------------------------------------" +
        Environment.NewLine + "Controllo IP.. " +
        Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------------------"



        Dim indir As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim perc As String = "\\" + indir + "\- Area condivisione"
        Dim fso As FileSystemObject
        Dim exists As Boolean
        fso = New FileSystemObject
        exists = fso.FolderExists(perc)
        If exists = True Then
            TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Green
            TextBox2.Text = "-------------------------------------------" +
            Environment.NewLine + "IP VALIDO: " + indir +
            Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------------------"


            Dim WshShell As WshShellClass = New WshShellClass

            Dim MyShortcut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut

            Dim NetworkFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts)

            MyShortcut = CType(WshShell.CreateShortcut(NetworkFolder & "\DACA-I File-Server.lnk"), IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)
            MyShortcut.TargetPath = "\\" + indir
            MyShortcut.Save()


        ElseIf exists = False Then
            TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red
            TextBox2.Text = "-------------------------------------------" +
            Environment.NewLine + "IP NON VALIDO: " + indir +
            Environment.NewLine + "-------------------------------------------" +
            Environment.NewLine + "Inserire un altro indirizzo:" +
            Environment.NewLine + "Il percorso specificato non contiene" +
            Environment.NewLine + "Directory DACA-I"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: `System.Directory.Exists` maybe?

Comment: @Charlieface already solved, just needed a TextBox2.Focus() to solve..